# mover un servo 360º en arduino

Tags: arduino

Estoy trabajando en un sistema de posicionamiento de antenas automático. Para ello tengo dos servomotores que se comunican con el programa Hamlib (http://hamlib.sourceforge.net/html/rotctld.1.html) por medio de el protocolo EasyCommII para recibir órdenes de posicionamiento.
El problema que estoy teniendo es a la hora de calibrar mis servos (https://www.servocity.com/sg12-series-servo-gearbox-7-1-ratio-640-rotation-2450-oz-in-1-12-sec-60/) ya que no consigo configurarlos para que hagan una rotación completa, de 360º. Me explico, cuando le mando órdenes de angulos menores de 180º hace el posicionamiento correcto, pero a partir de ahí empieza a deshacerlo, es decir, solo alcanza los 180º.
Me estoy basando en el programa SatTrackerII (https://sites.google.com/site/k6vugdiary/satellite-tracking-system/satellite-tracker-controller)

```
/ this function reinitializes the azimuth servo to updated min/max values
void reinitializeAzServo() {
  // save the new min/max parameters to EEPROM
  writeAzServoMinMaxToEEPROM();

  // set new min/max values for the servo attached
  AzServo.attach(PIN_AZSERVO,AzServoMin,AzServoMax);
  delay(20);

  // make sure the servo has aligned to the values
  MoveAzServo();
}


// this function reinitializes the elevation servo to updated min/max values
void reinitializeElServo() {
  // save the new min/max parameters to EEPROM
  writeElServoMinMaxToEEPROM();

  // set new min/max values for the servo attached
  ElServo.attach(PIN_ELSERVO,ElServoMin,ElServoMax);
  delay(20);

  // make sure the servo has aligned to the values
  MoveElServo();
}


// this function moves the azimuth servo by one degree in the correct direction
void MoveAzServo() {
  // calculate the next angle to move servo by 1 degree from its current position
  if (newAz > curAz) {
    curAz = curAz+1;
  }
  else if (newAz < curAz) {
    curAz = curAz-1;
  }

  // command the servo to move
  if (CCW_SERVOS) 
    //AzServo.write(curAz);
    AzServo.writeMicroseconds(map(curAz, 0, 360, AZMIN_DEFAULT, AZMAX_DEFAULT));
    //AzServo.writeMicroseconds(AZMIN_DEFAULT+double(curAz)*(AZMAX_DEFAULT-AZMIN_DEFAULT)/360.0); // added by tyson
  else
    //AzServo.write(180 - curAz);
    AzServo.writeMicroseconds(map(180-curAz, 0, 360, AZMIN_DEFAULT, AZMAX_DEFAULT));// added by tyson 
}


// this function moves the elevation servo by one degree in the correct direction
void MoveElServo() {
  // calculate the next angle to move servo by 1 degree from its current position
  if (newEl > curEl) {
    curEl = curEl+1;
  }
  else if (newEl < curEl) {
    curEl = curEl-1;
  }

  // command the servo to move
  ElServo.writeMicroseconds(map(curEl, +135, -135, ELMIN_DEFAULT, ELMAX_DEFAULT));
  // ElServo.write(curEl);
}

// ========================== END OF SERVO CONTROL ROUTINES =======================
```

Dejo adjunta la parte del código que controla el movimiento del servo.

Answer (score 0):

Según la documentación del servo indica que el rango máximo de rotación es de

```
Max PWM Range   500-2500μsec
```

No sé que vale `AzServoMin`y `AzServoMax` pero prueba a ponerles 500 y 2500 como dice en el datasheet a ver si tienes más suerte.

Comment: Gracias, pero si que hace rotaciones de 360º, por diseño tiene hasta 640 º, aproximadamente dos revoluciones completas. El problema es que no sabe reconocer los ángulos superiores a 180º.

Comment: ¿Estás 100% seguro que no es un servo normal de 180? A mi me ocurría básicamente lo mismo (hace aaaños) y recuerdo que era por eso. Has probado a hacerlo girar 360 sin esa libreria sino con otra para asegurarte que el servo se puede mover 360 por señal?

Comment: Estoy revisando la documentación del servo y es probable que si que pueda hacer más rotación pero la librería que usas es posible que esté configurada para otro tipo de servo. El tema es que el angulo de un servo por lo general se deriva del ancho de pulso de la señal y la frecuencia. Si la librería del servo no está configurada para los tuyos pues se comporta como uno de toda la vida. Voy a echar un vistazo más a fondo porque estoy oxidado a ver que saco en claro

Comment: Gracias. Si que estoy seguro porque he conseguido hacerle dar las casi 2 revoluciones de las que es capaz. En cuanto a la librería, es la genérica de Arduino, no se si hay alternativas